# Are there any known issues with Deja-Dup and Ubuntu One; notebly on restore?

Tags: ubuntu-one, backup, deja-dup, restore

Aloha,

I am planning a backup routine. I am thinking of using Deja-Dup and placing the backup in the default Ubuntu One folder. A while back I was making rsync backups and ran into problem when restoring.

The rsync backup was setup to copy my home directory, and it copied the ~/.local/share/ubuntuone, which caused conflicts when I restored the system.

RE: https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/im-setting-up-ubuntu-one-on-a-new-computer-or-re-installing-my-operating-system-how-should-i-do-this/

Should I set Deja-Dup to ignore this folder on backup? And are there any other concerns/issues with Ubuntu One and Deja-Dup on backup and restore?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

DD will automatically exclude the backup location folder from being backed up itself.   So of you backup to ~/Ubuntu One, that folder will be excluded.

That said, DD has built in support for Ubuntu One in modern versions of Ubuntu.  So instead of simply backing up to the default U1 folder and having your backup files synchronized to all your computers, DD can backup to a cloud folder in U1 that isn't synchronized by default.  This also means that the backup files won't take up any space on your local machine.  Simply select Ubuntu One from the drop down for the Backup Location preference.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It's good to be sure that DD won't backup it's storage location. The directory that I'm concerned about is '~/.local/share/ubuntuone'

Comment: There is no special logic for that folder, so with the default settings, it will back that folder up. Of course you can exclude it manually.